# Howto make a var. name with a var. in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, scope, variable-variables

I have some vars live:

```
int foo1;
int foo2;
..
```

and I want to reach them from:

```
for (int i = 1;i<=2;i++)
{
   // howto get foo1 and foo2?
}
```

how to get them?

EDIT, end what when it will be no int but a Opject *pointer;?

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible to me. Try to formulate it better and less sloppy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't; you need an array of some kind.  e.g.:

```
int foo[2];   /* Two elements, foo[0] and foo[1] */
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    foo[i] = i;
}
```

or:

```
int foo1;
int foo2;
int *p[] = { &foo1, &foo2 };   /* Array of pointers */
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    *p[i] = i;   /* Changes foo1 or foo2 */
}
```

I don't fully understand your last question, but if you mean that you want the data types to be `Object *` rather than `int`, then all you need to do is substitute `Object *` for `int` into my code examples above (other than for `int i = 0`, obviously).